# getting Eclipse to see recently added Drawables (png artwork)

Tags: android, eclipse, import, artwork

I'm having trouble getting Eclipse to see that I've just put a new image into my project when referencing that image using R.drawable.this_text

So I drag my png into myProject/res/drawable-hdpi in Eclipse's Project Explorer.  The name of the image is this_text and it's a png!

So I go into my application and I want to put this on the screen;  So here's the code for that...

```
private void setTitle()
{
ImageView title = new ImageView(this); //this extends activity
title.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.this_text);
...
}
```

This I have done before and each time I do it I experience the same thing:
if i just dragged my this_text.png into the Project Explorer in eclipse, the word "this_text" will be underlined in red, and not allow me to compile or proceed.  I try to F5 (refresh) the project.  I try refreshing the image foldr, the src, the actual java...etc!  I try closing and opening eclipse but nothing really works.  So I quit for afew minutes and work elsewhere in my application, and eventually this error goes away!

Well I'm impatient today-- And I'd rather know how to solve this incase I need to do any quick programming! So does anyone know what to do?

I'm  using eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 1.

Thanks- Ethan

Comment: That is quite odd. I am using the same version of eclipse and do it all the time. Is it possible you have some other plugins installed that are delaying the scanning and error detection?

Answer (score 1):

R files for android are generated. Rather than refreshing you should be able to CLEAN the project which should fix your issue. You could even just delete the error from the problems list which would allow for compilation to start and for the generated R file to be created. Or you could make a change to an xml which would also allow for the file to be regened. As always make sure you are up to date on your tool chain.

Comment: Cleaning the project is the first thing to try.

Comment: Thank you! I Cleaned my project and it went away.  I can't believe I didn't try that b4 hand! Thanks again.